# OSGI: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.3.5

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, osgi-bundle

I've been trying to apply configuration of a [DBAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) in my OSGi application and I keep getting the following error:

```java
10:12:59,285 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [DB]
10:12:59,285 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
10:12:59,285 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:200)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:166)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:98)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:453)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:439)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:414)
        at      at prodist.robot.equinox.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:37)
        at      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:493)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:270)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:331)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.3.5
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 40 common frames omitted
```

I've implemented an gradle module (`osgi-log`) to handle log only. This is his configuration:

```
group 'project'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.0.5'

    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.3.5'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.3.5'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback.db', name: 'logback-classic-db', version: '1.2.11.1'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
    implementation group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm', version: '5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm-commons', version: '5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm-util', version: '5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.aries.spifly', name: 'org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle', version: '1.3.5'
}
```

In general, to use log in other bundles, I set a dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'project', name: 'osgi-log'
}
```

Not sure if worth mentioning, but I'm trying to work local - meaning both application and database are installed and running under localhost. I'm using `mysql v.8.0.33`.

And finally this is my logback configuration:

```
  <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
      <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
      <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/osgi_app</url>
      <user>osgi_app</user>
      <password>osgi_app</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
```

I really don't understand why `BundleLoader` is struggling to find the `DBAppender` class.
Just a disclaimer that I don't fully understand this environment, osgi, bundle and logback-classic working under slf4j.

Comment: That class seems to migrate between `classic` and `core`. Try `core`

Comment: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-db

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback.db/logback-classic-db

Comment: `osgi-log` (bundle for handling log) already has the dependency `implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic-db', version: '1.2.11.1'` set. Maybe I should highlight it

Comment: Oops, so you do ;) I must confess I don't use Gradle, but needless to say that you've got a *runtime* dependency problem. Maybe that class is not getting into what is executed